# Best DB grid to use with lots of lookup fields

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, dbgrid

I have a table with a couple foreign keys, something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE project.gl(
  id BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  glaccount_id INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  project_id INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  booking_id INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  cc_id INT(11) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  cu_id INT(11) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  INDEX FK_gl_booking_id (booking_id),
  INDEX FK_gl_cc_id (cc_id),
  INDEX FK_gl_cu_id (cu_id),
  INDEX FK_gl_glaccount_id (glaccount_id),
  INDEX FK_gl_project_id (project_id),
  CONSTRAINT FK_gl_booking_id FOREIGN KEY (booking_id)
  REFERENCES project.booking (id) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT,
  CONSTRAINT ......
```

I would like to display this in a DBGrid, but of course I don't want all the `*_id`'s to show, but instead the data the id points to.
I don't want to use a query to resolve the id's, *(for now)* I want to use a plain `TTable`.

Which DBGrid variant would you recommend that can lookup foreign keys, using something like a DBLookupComboBox in the foreign key cell?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just create a [lookup field](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Defining_a_Lookup_Field). Then the TDBGrid automatically shows a combobox for that column where you can select from the available values. The key field is automatically updated then.

Answer (score 2):

See also TDBGridEh from [Ehlib](http://ehlib.com), it is more "light" than ExpressQuantumGrid but pretty powerful. It is a commercial product.

Answer (score 1):

I do use the [ExpressQuantumGrid](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/VCL/ExQuantumGrid/) from DeveloperExpress for this and many other tasks. It is very powerfull and mature and can have Lookup-Columns. But it is commercial and it is a very "heavy" component.